# 'class QMutex' has no member named 'EnterCriticalSection'

Tags: qt, qmutex

I'm using QT 4.8 and whenever i do a simple usage of QMutex, I get the compilation error of: 'class QMutex' has no member named 'EnterCriticalSection'

Sample:

```
void classA::write (int x)
{
   mutex->lock()
   ... do something
   mutex->unlock()
}
```

mutex is defined as a member in the class and initialized in the header.

Comment: Add more context, i.e. header declaration, initialization, actual code (not pseudo-code), complete compiler error with line information.